# How to link all category cards to all category pages in one hardcoded card?

Tags: php, database, symfony, hyperlink, twig

I'm busy working on my very first Symfony website about a restaurant so that means I'm new with Symfony. I was done with the categories page in which I show all categories of dishes. It consists of some cards which also serves as buttons in which the names of the categories are shown from the database. I retrieve all data needed with entities. I showed my code to the teacher but then then he told me that that wasn't what he expected to see. What he expected was that I only hardcoded one card and then let the for loop generate the rest of them which I did now but now I've come to the step of linking every card to it's corresponding page. Normally I would do that in every hardcoded category card by adding this: "path('ExamplePage')". But now I've only one hardcoded category card I'm kinda confused with how to link all category cards to their corresponding pages in that one harcoded card.

I did some attempts to realize this with different methods such as the slug method as advised by another teacher but all without success. However I came across a method and it letted me show all names of the categories and linked the category cards to their respective pages but there's one catch: The data doesn't come from the database but it's hardcoded but however I'll share the code of that method too. The school requires us that we fetch the names from the categories from the database and then display it inside a page.

Right now I really am stuck inside a vicious circle so I hope you can help me getting myself out of that vicious circle. Current code of categories page: <https://jsfiddle.net/Pencoder/gfxktp5w/3/ > Method which is closest to answer: https://jsfiddle.net/Pencoder/mkLpb4v8/.

Current code of Categories page:

```
{% extends "Restaurant_Balfisot_Categories_Base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg body-tertiary position-relative">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink1" href="{{ path("Categories") }}">Categories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink2 " href="{{ path("Register") }}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink3" href="{{ path("Profile") }}">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <a href= "{{ path('Home') }}"><img class= "nbLogo position-relative" src="/Pictures/Restaurant_Balfisot_Logo_(Picture_version).png"></a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink4" href="{{ path("Order") }}">Order</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link  text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink5" href="{{ path("Orders") }}">Orders</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link  text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink6" href="{{ path("Contact") }}">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink7" href="{{ path("About Us") }}">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

        {% for category in categories %}
            {% set cardClass = cycle(['card3', 'card4', 'card5', 'card6', 'card7', 'card8'], loop.index0) %}
                {#  <a href="{{ path('category', {'id': category.id}) }}"> #}
                    <div class="card {{ cardClass }}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% set textClass = cycle(['text9', 'text10', 'text11', 'text12', 'text13', 'text14'], loop.index0) %}
                            <h1 class="{{ textClass }} position-relative">{{ category.name }}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
        {% endfor %}

    <footer class= "footer position-relative">
        <p class= "text3 text-light position-relative">©</p>
        <p class= "text4 text-light position-relative">2023</p>
        <img class= "ftLogo position-relative" src="/Pictures/Restaurant_Balfisot_Logo_(Picture_version).png">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class= "fbLogo position-relative" src= "Pictures/FBLogo.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img class= "igLogo position-relative" src= "Pictures/IGLogo.png"></a>
        <a href= "https://twitter.com/home"><img class= "twLogo position-relative" src="Pictures/TWLogo.png"></a>
    </footer>

{% endblock %}
```

Method which I came the closest to my objective:

```
{% set categories = [
    {name: 'Category 1', link: path('my_route')},
    {name: 'Category 2', link: path('my_route')},
    {name: 'Category 3', link: path('my_route')}
] %}
```

Comment: What is the real question/problem here? The requirement of the task is that you need to store fetch/retrieve the categories out of a database?

Comment: Yeah, that part is true but the question is how I'm supposed to link every card to each respective category. Normally I would add in every card a <a> tag and then add the route to each page but now I've only one hardcoded card and somehow I need to add links to all categories.

Comment: Hi everyone, after I received some answers on my question I started researching and thinking about how I can realize my desired objective but then I came across a idea: "Making if statement which states that if for example the name of the category is Appetizers that it will link to Appetizers in that one hardcoded card". I've tried it and this method finally works! I'm so relieved because I've successfully freed myself out of the vicious circle. Lastly I've updated the code with the correct method to realize this so it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
{% extends "Restaurant_Balfisot_Categories_Base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg body-tertiary position-relative">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink1" href="{{ path("Categories") }}">Categories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink2 " href="{{ path("Register") }}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink3" href="{{ path("Profile") }}">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <a href= "{{ path('Home') }}"><img class= "nbLogo position-relative" src="/Pictures/Restaurant_Balfisot_Logo_(Picture_version).png"></a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink4" href="{{ path("Order") }}">Order</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link  text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink5" href="{{ path("Orders") }}">Orders</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link  text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink6" href="{{ path("Contact") }}">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light list-unstyled position-relative nLink7" href="{{ path("About Us") }}">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

        {% for category in categories %}
            {% set cardClass = cycle(['card3', 'card4', 'card5', 'card6', 'card7', 'card8'], loop.index0) %}
                 {# <a href="{{ path('category', {'id': category.id}) }}"> #}
       {% if category.name == 'Appetizers' %}
   <a href="{{ path('Appetizers') }}">
    {% elseif category.name == 'Main course' %}
    <a href="{{ path('Main Course') }}">
        {% elseif category.name == 'Desserts' %}
        <a href="{{ path('Desserts') }}">
        {% elseif category.name == 'Breakfast' %}
        <a href="{{ path('Breakfast') }}">
                {% elseif category.name == 'Snacks' %}
        <a href="{{ path('Snacks') }}">
                {% elseif category.name == 'Drinks' %}
        <a href="{{ path('Drinks') }}">
                  {% endif %}
            <div class="card {{ cardClass }}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% set textClass = cycle(['text9', 'text10', 'text11', 'text12', 'text13', 'text14'], loop.index0) %}
                            <h1 class="{{ textClass }} position-relative">{{ category.name }}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
        {% endfor %}

    <footer class= "footer position-relative">
        <p class= "text3 text-light position-relative">©</p>
        <p class= "text4 text-light position-relative">2023</p>
        <img class= "ftLogo position-relative" src="/Pictures/Restaurant_Balfisot_Logo_(Picture_version).png">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class= "fbLogo position-relative" src= "Pictures/FBLogo.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img class= "igLogo position-relative" src= "Pictures/IGLogo.png"></a>
        <a href= "https://twitter.com/home"><img class= "twLogo position-relative" src="Pictures/TWLogo.png"></a>
    </footer>

{% endblock %}
```